# Gitlab Pipeline: Firebase deploy 403

Tags: node.js, firebase, gitlab-ci, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I have one gitlab project and want to deploy the `master` branch to my production firebase project and the `develop` branch to another develop firebase project

Deploying `master` branch to firebase works. But deploying develop to firebase doesn't

Here's my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: node:10

before_script:
  - npm install
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
  - npm install -g firebase-tools

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - prod
  - test

deploy-prod:
  stage: prod
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://my.chronery.app
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - npm run build-prod
    - npm run deploy-prod

deploy-test:
  stage: test
  environment:
    name: development
    url: https://chronery-dev.firebaseapp.com
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - npm run build-dev
    - npm run deploy-dev
```

So `deploy-test` is the one, which doesn't work.
And here are the scripts of my package.json:

```
"build-dev": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --extract-css false --source-map",
"build-prod": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --extract-css false",
"deploy-dev": "firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN -P dev",
"deploy-prod": "firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN -P prod",
```

The pipeline fails when it wants to deploy it to dev.
So this script: `deploy-dev`

Here's the error:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 403, Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-project@0.0.1 deploy-dev: `firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN -P dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@0.0.1 deploy-dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Minor change:

```
firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN -P dev
```

Hope you created FIREBASE_TOKEN in gitlab

Comment: I even created a new token multiple times and it still doesn't work. And the stage for production deployment works. So the $FIREBASE_TOKEN is there definitely.